# Why are my social media icons huge?

Tags: html, css

I tried to add some social media icons to my header just now and they are about 10 times larger than they should be. I've gone through the css and used firebug and I can't find what is doing this.

I would like them to be their regular size and sit on the top right of the header. Thanks in advance!!

Here's what it looks like ( http://www.bolistylus.com ):

[image]

Here's the style.css:

```
a { 
    color: #254655; 
}

ul, ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 5.5em;
}

#page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body{
background: #f3f3f3;
border-top: none;
border-top: 10px solid #666666;
}

#page {
    margin: 0em auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

.singular.page .hentry {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0;
}

#branding{
background: #f3f3f3;
color: #000000;
border-top: none;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}

#site-title {
    /*margin-right: 270px;*/
    padding: 0.66em 0 0 0;
}

#site-title a {
    color: #111111;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#branding h1, header#branding a{  
text-align: left;
margin-right: 0;
}

#branding span{
text-align: center;
}

#branding img {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -.66em;
    width: 30%;
}

#branding .widget{
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
right: 7.6%;
}

#respond{ background: #E7DFD6; }                     

.welcome{
margin: 15px 60px;
background: #f3f3f3;
border: 1px solid #f6ff96;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
}

/* =Menu
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*.header_nav ul{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    }
*/

#branding img .sm-img {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -.66em;
    width: 100%;
}

.header_nav {
    background: #f3f3f3
    }


.header_nav .head-nav { 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    border-top: 1px solid #cfcec9;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: right
    }

.header_nav ul li{
    display: inline;
    }

.header_nav ul li a{ 
    padding: 10.5px 21px;
    color: #000000;
    }

.header_nav ul li a:hover, .menu ul li .current{
    color: #a8cb17;
    text-decoration: none;
    }



#access {
    background: #f3f3f3; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#access li {
    float: center;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#access a {

}
#access ul ul {

}
#access ul ul ul {

}
#access ul ul a {

}
#access a:focus {
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
}   
#access ul li:hover > ul {
}
#access .current_page_item > a,
#access .current_page_ancestor > a {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying a percentage width multiple times in your CSS, here are the lines:

```
    style.css (line 70)
    #branding img {
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: -0.66em;
        width: 30%; //remove
    }

    style.css (line 530)
    #branding img {
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: -7px;
        width: 100%; //remove
    }
```

Remove those and they should display ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your css here:

```
#branding img {
height: auto;
margin-bottom: -0.66em;
width: 3%; /* 3 not 30 */
```

}

In style.css line 70

Answer (score 1):

Line 70 of your style.css is setting a width attribute with a value of 30%.  This is causing your images to stretch to 30% of their container.

```
#branding img {
height: auto;
margin-bottom: -.66em;
width: 30%;
}
```

Adjust the width to a lower percentage or remove the line entirely.